# SoftEther service is not starting

Tags: services

I've followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-multi-protocol-vpn-server-using-softether) 3 times and every time I've destroyed the VM and started fresh.

SoftEther service is not starting automatically after reboot. Manual start works fine.

I'm not a seasoned Ubuntu admin, so please help me to find out how to check the log to see if there's any startup error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have similar issue, to create the service this file should be created:

`nano /lib/systemd/system/vpnserver.service`

> [Unit]
> Description=SoftEther VPN Server After=network.target
>
> [Service]
> Type=forking ExecStart=/usr/local/vpnserver/vpnserver start
> ExecStop=/usr/local/vpnserver/vpnserver stop
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target

The tutorial is outdated.

Response from [Omid Shojaee](https://askubuntu.com/users/1342547/omid-shojaee) at [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/softether-is-not-starting-after-reboot)